# Adjusting tab icon size based on platform in .NET MAUI app

Tags: maui

How do I set icon size by platform in a .NET MAUI app if I use `PNG` images as icons?

I'm able to do this if I use font as image source but how do I do it if I use `PNG` images?

Here's how I'm defining my tabs in `AppShell`:

```
<FlyoutItem Title="Home" Icon="home.png">
   <Tab Title="Cats" Icon="cat.png">
      <ShellContent Route="Cats" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Cats}" />
   </Tab>
   <Tab Title="Dogs" Icon="dog.png">
      <ShellContent Route="Dogs" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Dogs}" />
   </Tab>
</FlyoutItem>
```

In this example, I want to set the size of `cat.png` and `dog.png` by platform.

Answer (score 0):

In Maui, I tried several methods but couldn’t adjust the size of the icon image. I saw that someone added related functions in advance on github. You can follow up this issue: [Improve the image generation for specific use cases](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/11099).